# How to filter the data from state depending on the value of the input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm testing at the same page at the moment, later I will move it into other components. I have an input field that sends its value to the state, also I'm fetching data from a json to the state, and I'm displaying all the information from the state but I want to only display the information that has the same email as the input field. I'm sending it with a button.

I'm just needing like a function of a way to filter the display but i can't understand how to do it.

```js
class Testing extends Component {
  state = { data: [], value: "", filteredData: "" };
  handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

async componentDidMount() {
    await fetch("http://tenjoucesar.github.io/data.json")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({ data });
      });
  }


handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let email = this.state.value;
    fetch("https://tenjoucesar.github.io/data.json")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        let result = data.filter(person => person.email === email);
        this.setState({ filteredData: result });
      });
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
  }
```

Everything here works, Form "is on the same jsx

```
   <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                  <input
                    type="email"
                    value={this.state.value}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                  />
                  <input
                    type="submit"
                    value="Submit"
                  />
                  </div>
                </form>
```

How do i display the data?

```
         <ul>
                {data.map(person => {
                  return (
                    <div className="result" key={person.email}>
                      <h3 className="heading-tertiary">
                        {person.name}, &nbsp;{person.age}
                      </h3>
                      <p className="paragraph--result">{person.notes}</p>
                          );
                 })}
```

I am displaying everything, also sending the value to the state, how can i only display the data with the same email? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this help you. you were calling two times api for data. I have change it for better performance.

```
'use strict';

class Testing extends React.Component {
    state = { data: [], value: "", filteredData: [] };
    handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

  async componentDidMount() {
      await fetch("http://tenjoucesar.github.io/data.json",{mode: 'cors'})
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          this.setState({ data });
        });
    }

  handleSubmit(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      let email = this.state.value;

      const filtered = this.state.data.filter((e) => e.email == email);

      this.setState({
        filteredData:filtered
      })

    }

    handleChange(e) {
      this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
    }

    InfomData = (person) => {
        return (
            <div className="result" key={person.email}>
                <h3 className="heading-tertiary">
                {person.name}, &nbsp;{person.age}
                </h3>
                <p className="paragraph--result">{person.notes}</p>
            </div>
        )
    }

    render () {

        const dataToRender = this.state.filteredData.map(
            (e) => this.InfomData(e) 
        )

        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <input
                        type="email"
                        value={this.state.value}
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                    />
                    <input
                        type="submit"
                        value="Submit"
                    />
                </form>
                {dataToRender}
            </div>
        )
    }

}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Testing />,
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Comment: you did it, now works!! Thank you so much, i spend hours serching for an answer. Thanks man! also thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

```
let result = []
data.forEach(person => {
          if(person.email === 'targetemail@whatever.com')
          { result.push(
              <div className="result" key={person.email}>
              <h3 className="heading-tertiary">
                {person.name}, &nbsp;{person.age}
              </h3>
              <p className="paragraph--result">{person.notes}</p>
              </div>)
          }
}
```